# Matplotlib missing x tick labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, python-3.6

Once I run the code below, the x tick labels for the third plot, ax3, does not show up. Yet, I only removed the x tick labels for ax1 and ax2. Any solution to having the dates appear on the x axis of my third plot, ax3?

```
plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((8,1),(0,0), rowspan=4, colspan=1)
ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=10, prune='lower'))
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)

ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((8,1),(4,0), rowspan=2, colspan=1, sharex = ax1)
plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)

ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((8,1),(6,0), rowspan=2, colspan=1, sharex = ax1)
ax3.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(10))
ax3.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(20))

'''
# This has been ***removed*** in corrected version
for label in ax3.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(45)
        plt.xlabel('Dates') #This label does not appear in the figure either
'''

ax3.yaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=5, prune='upper'))

main.dropna(inplace=True)                          
main['sales1'].plot(ax=ax1)
main['sales2'].plot(ax=ax1)
cmain.plot(ax=ax2)
main[['rollsales1', 'rollsales2']].plot(ax=ax3)

'''
# This has been added to corrected version.   
plt.setp(ax3.xaxis.get_label(), visible=True, text='Dates')
plt.setp(ax3.get_xticklabels(), visible=True, rotation=30, ha='right')
'''    

plt.show()
```

Comment: You have way too much code here.  Please provide a **minimal**, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: Shortened it down to where I think the issue may fall under. Thanks for the input.

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: I am using matplotlib 2.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In matplotlib, using `sharex` or `sharey` turns off the ticklabels by default in version 2.  So you can drop the pieces of code that set the label visibility to `False`.  Also, rather than iterating over each label to change the parameters, you can set the parameters for all of them in one shot using `setp`.

I had to make fake data to simulate your graphs, so my data may look bizarre.

```
plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((8,1),(0,0), rowspan=4, colspan=1)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((8,1),(4,0), rowspan=2, colspan=1, sharex=ax1)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((8,1),(6,0), rowspan=2, colspan=1, sharex=ax1)

ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=10, prune='lower')
ax3.yaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=5, prune='upper'))

main.dropna(inplace=True)
main['sales1'].plot(ax=ax1)
main['sales2'].plot(ax=ax1)
cmain.plot(ax=ax2)
main[['rollsales1', 'rollsales2']].plot(ax=ax3)

# set the xaxis label
plt.setp(ax3.xaxis.get_label(), visible=True, text='Dates')
# set the ticks
plt.setp(ax3.get_xticklabels(), visible=True, rotation=30, ha='right')
# turn off minor ticks
plt.minorticks_off()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It works! I really appreciate it! I added two figures to the top(x-axis dates are monthly), first to show the results and then as I zoom in. As a final follow up question, how could I fill out more of the x-axis? In the second figure, how do I get the months to show up upon zooming in?

Comment: Try using `plt.tight_layout()` before you adjust the vertical spacing between the graphs.  Also please remember to mark the question as answered :)

Comment: I tried using `plt.tight_layout()` but for some reason it's still not working.